# Python Script to get disassembled output of an EXE file

Tags: disassembly, python, ghidra

I'm pretty new to Ghidra, and looking to use it's API (headless analyzer) and get the assembled file through command line using python.

Here is my code, which is likely far from the correct code. It gives error, and I am stuck. Would you please help?

The command I am using to run the script is:

```
analyzeHeadless ~/Desktop/ghidra_9.1-BETA_DEV   DNETSamples.gpr -scriptPath ~/Desktop/ghidra_9.1-BETA_DEV  -postScript disassemble.py    -process -recursive
```

And this is disassemble.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from ghidra.util.task import ConsoleTaskMonitor
from ghidra.app.cmd.disassemble import DisassembleCommand
from ghidra.app.script import GhidraScript
from  ghidra.program.model.address import AddressSet



addset = AddressSet()
addset.add(currentAddress)
cmd = DisassembleCommand(addset, None, True)
cmd.doDisassembly​(ConsoleTaskMonitor(), currentProgram, 0)
```

The error is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value`:

```
INFO  SCRIPT: ghidra_9.1-BETA_DEV/ghidra_decomp.py (HeadlessAnalyzer)
Exception in thread "Python script execution thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:57)
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:70)
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:74)
    at org.python.core.PySyntaxError.<init>(PySyntaxError.java:31)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.fixParseError(ParserFacade.java:95)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parse(ParserFacade.java:190)
    at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:2185)
    at org.python.core.\__builtin__.execfile_flags(\__builtin__.java:527)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:286)
    at ghidra.python.GhidraPythonInterpreter.execFile(GhidraPythonInterpreter.java:232)
    at ghidra.python.PythonScriptExecutionThread.run(PythonScriptExecutionThread.java:51)
```

Comment: What error? We can’t see your screen.

Comment: updated my post to include the error.

Comment: @Memphis4Ever maybe include how you run the this script. What parameters to `analyzeHeadless` do you provide?

Comment: I've run your command with updated paths (and under windows) and it run successfully. But I would look into this 'non-byte value' info that Ghidra reports. Try checking your script in hex-editor. Maybe there's some non-ASCII character in your script?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to delete your project (or use new) and add [`-deleteproject`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/analyzeHeadlessREADME.html#deleteProject]) next time when you run your `analyzeHeadless` script.